# how to sum input values in angular

Tags: angular

i create multiple product with increment decrement for quantity like shopping cart...
i have multiple product list with quantity increment ..i want to sum total qty from multiple products ... how to sum this

[image]

this is my output:  9

how to get this in angular

sum operation only enough for me when click on button

Answer (score 0):

You could have event emitter that create an event whenever the user click the minus or plus button of the child item component. When you emit the event you send some data, whatever it was clicked plus or minus and update the sum variable in the parent component.
See https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#sending-data-to-a-parent-component

Comment: i am using  event emitter but it shows values of current cliked button not sum

Comment: i got count of currently clicked button not shows sum of values

Comment: You could just add 1 to sum variable if the event AddEvent is fired or subtract 1 is the SubEvent  is fired.

Comment: incrementValue(step: number = 1): void {  let inputValue = this._value + step; this._value = inputValue; this.eventEmitter.emit(inputValue);  } am using this one for plus & minus

Comment: if i click minus means it calls incrementValue(-step) & click plus means it calls  incrementValue(+step) so it works fine.... but i want to sum all these input values

Comment: From parent: you should have a global variable sum that is initially 0 and then the when you catch the event and add 1 to sum, and vice versa for minus

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using reactive forms.
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms